# Working with associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have a very simple association. A User has_many Emails, this association works as expected with create/update/delete.

How ever when I attempt to display the information this is where things become some what difficult.

In my controller I have the following bit of code:

```
def prospective_user
    @users = Account::User.all_by_user_status(0)     
    @users.each do |u|
        u.email = u.email.get_primary_email
    end
end
```

What this should do is create an instance of the Account::Email model with a single record.

The method get_primary_email looks like this:

```
def self.get_primary_email
    first :conditions => ["is_primary = 1"]
end
```

The issue I am seeing is with in my view, I am getting the exception below. This is a bit confusing as I am not looping over the email object.

`undefined method each' for #<Account::Email:0x7fcc3a5c49d8>`

The code I am using to test with is this:

```
<% @users.each do |u|%>
    <p>
        <%=debug(u.email)%>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like that instead:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :emails
   has_one  :primary_email, :class_name => 'Email',
                            :conditions => { is_primary: 1 }
 end
```

Then you can call `user.primary_email` directly

```
# your controller
def prospective_user
  @users = Account::User.includes(:primary_email).where(:status => 0)
end

# your view
<% for user in @users %>
  <%= user.primary_email %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Making this change created a new exception of undefined method `get_primary_email' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x7fdd6954c7e0>

Comment: I updated your controller code as well. It's a lot cleaner now ;)